# Xamarin.iOS: Deploying to device fails with "failed to acquire command execution log"

Tags: iphone, deployment, xamarin.ios, device

My iOS app built in Visual Studio with a Xamarin Mac build host runs on the iOS simulator but does not deploy to the device. The Mac server log shows this:

```
[2013-07-30 13:28:45.7] Handling with command: [Build: CommmandUrl=Build] (20)
[2013-07-30 13:28:45.7] Attempting to acquire command execution lock, timeout set to 00:10:00
[2013-07-30 13:30:56.4] Error: Failed to acquire command execution log, the request timed out
[2013-07-30 13:30:56.4] Command [Build: CommmandUrl=Build] finished (17)
```

Incidentally, is that a typo in line 3 - shouldn't it read "lock" not "log"?

We are using Xamarin Studio 4.0.10 (build 7), Xamarin.iOS 6.4.0.2 (Business Edition), XCode 4.6.2 (2067.2) Build 4H1003.

What is the cause of this error, and how can we get past it?

Comment: If you have a business edition it would maybe be a better and faster option to contact support at Xamarin.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I created a forum post on Xamarin and contacted support. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6536/visual-studio-2012-hangs-on-build-command-for-device-deployments I'll post back here if anything comes of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking with Xamarin folks I was told that a fix was included in the Beta for Xamarin.iOS 6.4.1. I switched my Xamarin Studio to the Beta Channel (via the update dialog) and am now able to deploy as before.